# How can I prevent the issue that in cmd, if I do run a command that turns out to have a lot of output then I can't see output of previous commands?

Tags: windows, windows-7, cmd.exe

How can I prevent the problem that in a `cmd` shell, if I run a command that turns out to have a lot of output then I can't see output of previous commands?

And I'm talking about if I didn't run it with head or tail or outputting to a file.

I'm thinking of some feature that either automatically cuts it off if it's so long that it's going to wipe everything else out. Or, has enough memory allocated to the window to let me scroll back to whatever was before it.

My computer is on Windows 7 though it is probably an issue with later versions of windows too.

Comment: hmm, in linux I'd pass the output through tee or output to a text file and tail that. Or do you want to clear the output periodically?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek well, i'm talking about a case were the swamp of output comes unexpectedly.. hence my question says not using tail or head or outputting to a file. I don't want to clear the output periodically!!! I want to read the output.  I guess if the window logged everything to a file then that'd be useful

Comment: would the 'classic' > foo.text work?

Comment: No this is when I don't expect there to be a swamp of output, I wouldn't do > foo.txt for almost every command. That's why your edit is my title isn't exactly what i'm asking

Comment: I was mainly annoyed by the problemo.. and trying to grok the overall problem :D

Comment: Set the "screen buffer size", "lines" to a large value. I have mine set to 5000 lines. Then you can use the scrollbar to scroll up ...

Comment: @DavidPostill there is no "5000", maybe you are seeing "500"(which is maybe a default).. It can go to 999. If you think you've typed in 5000 then use the left and right arrows to scroll through to see how many zeros you have. Can you share a screenshot showing you have 5000 there?

Comment: @barlop https://i.stack.imgur.com/rubhh.png

Comment: @DavidPostill what windows version is that?! I don't see it on 7 or 10 (though maybe my windows versions arent so up to date)

Comment: @barlop Windows 7

Comment: @DavidPostill something very strange is going on here.. a moment ago I was limited to 999 but now mine goes above 5000 https://i.imgur.com/n23iSuv.png  is yours  limited to 5000?

Comment: @barlop It goes up to 9999

Comment: @DavidPostill ah I see.. command history buffer size is limited to 999, screen buffer size height is limited to 9999.  You can post that as an answer..

Comment: @barlop Already posted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If I run a command that generates lot of output then I can't see the output of previous commands

You can change the `cmd` shell window properties "screen buffer size", "height" to a value up to 9999. Then you can use the scrollbar to scroll up.

To do this go to Menu > Default > Layout Tab:

Example:

[image]